# Add target to button of collectionview cell inside tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a tableview cell inside which i have added collectionview cell ( for horizontal scrolling).

Now i want to push to other navigation controller on button of any cell of horizontal collectionview. How to do it ? O

Code :

**ViewController.swift :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var categories = ["Action", "Drama", "Science Fiction", "Kids", "Horror"]
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categories[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow
        return cell
    }

}
```

**CategoryRow.swift**

```
class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell

cell.button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ViewController.goToLookAtPage(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
        let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
        let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }

}
```

**where do i declare goToLookAtPage function ?**

**VideoCell.swift**

```
class VideoCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
}
```

Comment: as per my understanding it should be in `CategoryRow` class , then you need to call delegate or closure  to notify your vc

Comment: I understand that should be in goToLookAtPage too. And there you can call a segue, instantiate a new view controller or post a notification to call your view controller from anywhere else

Comment: I would suggest to call the delegate from VideoCell to CategoryRow and then have the viewcontroller implement CategoryRow delegates and you can do the navigation there.

Comment: @MikeAlter yes but how to call anything on button click ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delclare it 
on  `CategoryRow` Class also declare global  closure

like

```
var buttonTapped:((CategoryRow?) -> Void)? = nil
```

Now we have `closure` to call

Implement  `goToLookAtPage` as below

```
func goToLookAtPage(_ sender:UIButton) {

    if let btnAction = self.buttonTapped {
         btnAction(self)
      }
}
```

Now in your `ViewController` add following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.buttonTapped = {(cell) -> Void in
          //You Got your response , do push in main Thread  
}
```

Hope it helps to you

Comment: Thank you :) it worked. And can you tell me if on a click i how can i change the title of that button ?

Comment: you  can change it on `goToLookAtPage` you have sender

Answer (score 0):

In your button handler function get the button's position where sender is your button.

```
let position = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.collectionView)
```

Get the index path for the given position.

```
let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: position)
```

Get the model from your data source with the index path.

```
let model = self.data[indexPath.row]
```

Now that you have your data model, pass it to your destination and push your view controller or whatever.

Comment: This is not answer of the question , this is the question `where do i declare goToLookAtPage function ?`

Comment: @MikeAlter I think you are right. After your warning I realized collection view cell is inside a table view cell. And I don't even want to know why is it so. Thanks mate.